# Matcher/Pattern in Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, design-patterns, matcher

I've got a code which involves using Matcher and Pattern classes, however I've got a text which contains multiple instances of the same "pattern". My code however returns every found match and puts it in a single string. I want to put every match found in a different string/array. Can you give me an example code?

Comment: The code is not important here, I just want to know how I would let the matcher return 1 match, save it into a so called "string1", then proceed to search for other matches. If it finds another match it would put it in "string2" etc.

Comment: Store them in a List<String>.

Comment: I know where I could store them, I'm wondering HOW I can return a match, store it into a seperate string or stringarray, and proceed to search for more matches...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear to me.

But,
I assume, Your emphasized textinput strings are in array or list. 
And you want to create new array or list from the input strings which matches the regex.

Then here is the solution for this:

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Java");//any regex
        List<String> inputStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> matched = new ArrayList<String>();
        //test strings
        inputStrings.add("Java hello");
        inputStrings.add("Javaaa");
        inputStrings.add("aaaJavaaa");
        inputStrings.add("Jvaaa");
        //do
        for (String curStr : inputStrings) {
            Matcher matcher = p.matcher(curStr);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                matched.add(curStr);
            }
        }
```